# Chaining methods in Rust

Tags: rust, method-chaining

I have recently tried to create a simple builder pattern that allows for chaining methods together.

The API for it should look similar to this:

```rust
let chained = MethodChainer::new()
                  .then(method1)
                  .then(method2)
                  .then(method3);

chained.run(x); // Will be equivalent to `method3(method2(method1(x)))`
```

However, I'm struggling to come up with a good implementation.

One option, is to store the chained method and when `then` is called, swap the chained method with the following:

```rust
fn then(self, new_method: /*some method type*/){
    self.chain = |x| {new_method(self.chain(x))}
}
```

Or something similar. But this approach limits controlling how the functions are called and how I can intervene in the middle (e.g, want to allow a "debug mode" that when activated, it will print each result from each method that was chained).

Optimally, for me - the "best" implementation would put all chained methods into one `Vec`, and then running them will loop over that `Vec` and execute each method. But this is not possible in safe rust due to type restrictions, and I'm not sure if its even *possible* to implement it even in unsafe rust...

That is why I'm asking here - is this feature possible to implement (safe or unsafe rust)? If so - then how?

Comment: What's the benefit of this API vs chaining like this? `let chained = MethodChainer::new().method1().method2().method3();`

Comment: The methods may be defined externally to the `MethodChainer`, so I can't assume they are implemented internally in the `MethodChainer`. Maybe a user will use this API and define a new `method_whatever` that does something else...

Comment: Also, I don't think this will make a difference in the actual implementation of the `MethodChainer`. There is still the main problem - how will it keep track of the methods that have been chained?

Comment: You have to either restrict "methods" to be something that coerce to fn pointer, or to box them for storage.

Comment: @IvanC yes, that is definitely OK

Comment: In fact, they all will have to implement `Fn(X) -> Y` or `fn(X) -> Y` (prefferably the first, but both are fine by me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vector approach is a bit tricky, because you would need to be generic about the intermediate types of your chaining. This, in turn, would require a different number of generic parameters, depending on how often `then` is called - so the type needs to change on every call of `then`. We cannot list all of the types in a long list, as that would require [variadic generics](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/376) and Rust doesn't have that. You can however use a generic type to nest your chained methods, i.e. keep the old instance in a field of the new instance. One problem that occurs is the implementation of `run` - we would to compare the inner value against some maker to notice that we are in the base-case, i.e. there are no more nested methods. To get around that, one can use a helper trait `Run` and a marker type that indicates "no more nested methods" and can then have its own implementation of the `Run` trait. If Rust ever gets [specialization](https://doc.rust-lang.org/unstable-book/language-features/specialization.html) in stable, we could probably use `()` as a marker type instead and get rid of the `Run` trait. Anyways, here is what I came up with:

```rust
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct BaseChainer;

struct MethodChainer<X, Y, F, I> {
    _x: PhantomData<X>,
    _y: PhantomData<Y>,
    f: F,
    inner: I,
}

impl<X> MethodChainer<X, X, fn(X) -> X, BaseChainer> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            _x: PhantomData,
            _y: PhantomData,
            f: |x| x,
            inner: BaseChainer,
        }
    }
}

impl<X, Y, F, I> MethodChainer<X, Y, F, I> {
    pub fn then<G, Z>(self, new_method: G) -> MethodChainer<X, Z, G, MethodChainer<X, Y, F, I>>
    where
        F: Fn(X) -> Y,
        G: Fn(Y) -> Z,
    {
        MethodChainer {
            _x: PhantomData,
            _y: PhantomData,
            f: new_method,
            inner: self,
        }
    }
}

trait Run<X> {
    type Y;

    fn run(&self, x: X) -> Self::Y;
}

impl<X> Run<X> for BaseChainer {
    type Y = X;

    fn run(&self, x: X) -> X {
        x
    }
}

impl<X, Y, Z, F, I> Run<X> for MethodChainer<X, Z, F, I>
where
    F: Fn(Y) -> Z,
    I: Run<X, Y = Y>,
{
    type Y = Z;

    fn run(&self, x: X) -> Z {
        (self.f)(self.inner.run(x))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let plus_one = |x: i32| x + 1;
    let chained = MethodChainer::new()
        .then(plus_one)
        .then(|x| x.to_string())
        .then(|s| s + " - wow!");
    println!("{}", chained.run(5));
}
```

It could probably be shorter, but should get you started.

---

Note that this forces you to either make all functions taking a `MethodChainer` to be generic over its `F` and `I` generic parameters.

Comment: Interesting take! So you are basically using a recursive type to create artificially variadic generics. which allows you to express all of the functions in the way. I know that rust has monomorphization for generics, so how do you think this will cope if we were to do something like: `for _ in 0..1000 { let chainer = chainer.then(plus_one); }` for example?

Comment: Seems that it does not compile due to type mismatch that occurs over the `I` generic :(

Comment: Yes, that was expected as `then` returns a new type that is more nested than the previous one, so the type of `chainer` would have to change in every iteration. If we want to do that, we need the `chainer` to _not_ know what exactly it is that is being called in `inner`, i.e. make the type of `inner` something like `Box<dyn Run<X, Y = Y>>` - but then we have different types for the last intermediate type again. See my other answer for an approach that is more sloppy with allocations, but handles this scenario

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is another approach that is similar to what you first imagined, but comes at the cost of a lot of `Box`ing. To get rid of the problem with intermediate types, we modify all functions that are used to run on `Box<dyn Any>` instead of on the concrete types. Then, we can store all of those modified functions as `Box<dyn Fn(Box<dyn Any>) -> Box<dyn Any>>` - and those we can store in a `Vec`! The difference to my other answer, is that the functions know themselves how to interpret the data that is being piped through them, it is not the chainer that has to do the interpreting. An example implementation:

```rust
struct DynamicChainer<X, Y> {
    fns: Vec<Box<dyn Fn(Box<dyn Any>) -> Box<dyn Any>>>,
    _phantom: PhantomData<fn(X) -> Y>,
}

impl<X> DynamicChainer<X, X> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            fns: Vec::new(),
            _phantom: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

impl<X: 'static, Y: 'static> DynamicChainer<X, Y> {
    pub fn run(&self, x: X) -> Box<Y> {
        let x: Box<dyn Any> = Box::new(x);
        let y = self.fns.iter().fold(x, |acc, f| f(acc));
        y.downcast().expect("Something went wrong with our closures")
    }

    pub fn then<Z: 'static, G: Fn(Y) -> Z + 'static>(self, g: G) -> DynamicChainer<X, Z> {
        let any_g = move |any_y: Box<dyn Any>| {
            let y = any_y
                .downcast()
                .expect("Something went wrong with our closures");
            let z = g(*y);
            Box::new(z) as Box<dyn Any>
        };

        let Self { mut fns, .. } = self;
        fns.push(Box::new(any_g));
        DynamicChainer {
            fns,
            _phantom: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let plus_one = |x: i32| x + 1;
    let chainer = DynamicChainer::new()
        .then(plus_one)
        .then(|x| x.to_string())
        .then(|s| s + " - wow!");
    println!("{}", chainer.run(5));

    let mut chainer = DynamicChainer::new();
    for _ in 0..1000 {
        chainer = chainer.then(plus_one);
    }
    println!("{}", chainer.run(5));
}
```

We could spare some memory by only allocating one `Box` for each type and moving in and out of this slot (for example, with [`anymap`](https://docs.rs/anymap/latest/anymap/)).

The downside of this approach is that `Any` requires the types to be `'static`, i.e. none of the types could be generic over lifetimes.

Comment: Another interesting answer! But its sad that it requires the heavy usage of `Box` due to not knowing object size at compile time :(

Comment: Well, like I said, you could reduce the number of allocations by reusing the same box for values of the same type, but that is left as an exercise to the reader :)